# What is the difference between conventional and on-screen OCR?

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I've been wondering about the difference between the screen OCR and the usual scanned text OCR. I've been using FineReader (and tried some other programs) for years, and I know that they are usually very picky about the scanning resolution. To such an extent that they would fail to recognize text captured from the screen. To me it looks counter-intuitive since an on-screen text is often practically noiseless due to the perfect single-colour background. I see that Abbyy (FineReader producer) now offers [ScreenshotReader](http://www.abbyy.com/screenshot_reader/). So they have a separate product for the seemingly same task, just because of this resolution problem? Am I missing something important? (Beyond the desire to earn more money :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, OCR quality benefits a lot from knowing the right resolution.

When you OCR graphic files they often contain metadata with resolution and OCR program can use that. Resolution in metadata can be wrong and then using it blindly will make matters worse. Some files will not contain resolution data at all. This is why high-end programs don't rely on that metadata alone - they also try to deduce the correct resolution by looking at objects that could turn out to be characters using their relative size and other features.

The screenshot reading program you refer to can improve screenshot recognition experience by two key things. First it knows the exact resolution and can make use of that to improve OCR and also it knows there's no noise and no distortions and no other similar artifacts on the image and so some preprocessing steps can be skipped which improves speed and increases OCR quality. Second it provides a lot of usability improvements - you don't need to save the screenshot to a file, you can easily set the recognition area right over the source program window, I guess there're other UI improvements which together just make OCRing pieces of screen image easier and faster.

Comment: I of course agree about the feature difference, but my question was mainly about why traditional OCR works so poorly for screenshots. So do I understand you right that the screenshot reader can be better in OCR because lacks some algorithms, necessary for scan OCR but potentially reducing screenshot analysis quality?

Comment: I am also a bit confused by your explanation of how OCR benefits from knowing the resolution. Both printed and on-screen text can be tiny and huge. How can a program derive anything from the pixel hight of a grapheme?

Comment: @texnic: Yes, text can be tiny or huge but there's a lower limit on how tiny it can be on screen - otherwise user will have hard times reading it. Meanwhile paper documents have a wider range - fine print can be much smaller than the smallest practical text on screen. When dealing with ranges the smaller the range the better is the guess.